# Onsen ui alert dialog get value from input tag and how to close dialog

Tags: dialog, onsen-ui

I have a problem with the input text on onsen alert dialog

1. when I click OK button dialog not hide
2. how to get password value from dialog input tag

```html
<ons-button modifier="tappable" onclick=" 

ons.createAlertDialog('alert.html').then(function(alertDialog) {
      alertDialog.show();
    });
     "
>Test2</ons-button>


<script type="text/ons-template" id="alert.html">
  <ons-alert-dialog animation="default" cancelable>
    <div class="alert-dialog-title">Warning!</div>
    <div class="alert-dialog-content">
      <input id="password" ng-model="password" class="text-input " type="number" 
    pattern="[0-9]*" inputmode="numeric" placeholder="password" value="" autofocus>
    </div>
    <div class="alert-dialog-footer">
      <button class="alert-dialog-button" onclick="alertDialog.hide()">OK</button>
    </div>
  </ons-alert-dialog>
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You will need to add your data to a global variable or push it to the factory as it appears you are using Angular.

Also, you need to register your dialogue to a controller / variable as well so you can close it.  The demo on the tutorial site is for vanilla right now, but the concept is the same.

Here is how this works:  http://tutorial.onsen.io/?framework=vanilla&category=Reference&module=dialog

JS:

```
var showDialog = function(id) {
  document
    .getElementById(id)
    .show();
};

var hideDialog = function(id) {
  document
    .getElementById(id)
    .hide();
};

var fromTemplate = function() {
  var dialog = document.getElementById('dialog-3');

  if (dialog) {
    dialog.show();
  }
  else {
    ons.createDialog('dialog.html')
      .then(function(dialog) {
        dialog.show();
      });
  }
   };
```

Markup:

```
<ons-page>
  <ons-toolbar>
    <div class="center">Dialogs</div>
  </ons-toolbar>

  <ons-list>
    <ons-list-header>Showing dialogs</ons-list-header>
    <ons-list-item tappable onclick="showDialog('dialog-1')">Simple dialog</ons-list-item>
    <ons-list-item tappable onclick="showDialog('dialog-2')">Alert dialog</ons-list-item>
    <ons-list-item tappable onclick="fromTemplate()">From template</ons-list-item>
    <ons-list-header>Notifications</ons-list-header>
    <ons-list-item tappable onclick="ons.notification.alert('Hello, world')">Alert</ons-list-item>
    <ons-list-item tappable onclick="ons.notification.confirm({message: 'Are you ready?'})">Confirmation</ons-list-item>
    <ons-list-item tappable onclick="ons.notification.prompt({message: 'What is your name?'})">Prompt</ons-list-item>
  </ons-list>
</ons-page>

<ons-dialog id="dialog-1">
  <div style="text-align: center; padding: 10px;">
    <p>
      This is a dialog.
    <p>

    <p>
      <ons-button onclick="hideDialog('dialog-1')">Close</ons-button>
    </p>
  </div>
</ons-dialog>

<ons-alert-dialog id="dialog-2">
  <div class="alert-dialog-title">Warning!</div>
  <div class="alert-dialog-content">
    An error has occurred!
  </div>
  <div class="alert-dialog-footer">
    <button class="alert-dialog-button" onclick="hideDialog('dialog-2')">Cancel</button>
    <button class="alert-dialog-button" onclick="hideDialog('dialog-2')">OK</button>
  </div>
</ons-alert-dialog>

<ons-template id="dialog.html">
  <ons-dialog id="dialog-3">
    <div style="text-align: center; padding: 10px;">
      <p>
        This dialog was created from a template.
      <p>

      <p>
        <ons-button onclick="hideDialog('dialog-3')">Close</ons-button>
      </p>
    </div>
  </ons-dialog>
</ons-template>
```